# How to INSERT all record from one table to another in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I am beginner please help to copy all records from 'first' table to 'second' table.

first table has 6 columns

```
| Item_Id | Item_Name | Unit | Quantity | Rate | Total_Amt |
```

And second one has one more additional column

```
| Sr_No | Item_Id | Item_Name | Total_Unit | Total_Quantity | Rate | Total_Amt |
```

Comment: you can use `AUTO_INCREMENT` for your Sr_No

Comment: totdayssales table has one additional column named "SrNo" what about that.. I am facing problem to add value to that column.. i.e i want to add all record from new_bill to todayssale table with "serialnumber" column. –

Comment: while creating table you can set your Sr_No like this `Sr_No int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` this will auto fill the entries in that column

Answer (score 4):

Try [`INSERT INTO...SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

```
INSERT INTO 
    todayssales(Item_Id, Item_Name, Total_Unit, Total_Quantity, Rate, Total_Amt)
SELECT Item_Id, Item_Name, Unit, Quantity, Rate, Total_Amt
  FROM new_bill
```

In your second table (todayssales) you can set `AUTO_INCREMENT` on `Sr_No` so that can be filled automatically.

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a414d/1)

Comment: totdayssales table has one additional column named "SrNo" what about that..

I am facing problem to add value to that column..

i.e i want to add all record from new_bill to todayssale table with "serialnumber" column.

Comment: @AnandKore - See my updates. You can set `AUTO_INCREMENT` on `Sr_No` if you want it to add values automatically.

Comment: @Anand_K47 - Did the answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
insert into todayssales( Item_Id, Item_Name, Total_Unit, Total_Quantity, Rate, Total_Amt)
 select Item_Id, Item_Name, Unit, Quantity, Rate, Total_Amt
  FROM new_bill
```